# A calendar app for repetitive activities?

Tags: calendar

I'm looking for a calendar app (doesn't matter the platform) that is able to schedule repetitive activities, for example, I'll have a list of activities like a gym routine:

```
Act 1: Chest/abs.
Act 2: Back.
Act 4: Shoulders/abs.
Act 5: Legs.
Act 6: Arms/abs.
Act 8: Cardio
Act 9: Meh
```

I want to be able to fit all this activities on a calendar and set it to skip Wednesdays and Sundays, I also want the starting date to be dynamically set, for example if I happen to skip a leg day, I want to be able to reschedule everything again on my calendar, having the leg day done one day after the day that was skipped.

I've tried Google Calendar, but it doesn't reschedule when i skip a day, and that's something that i really desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[org-mode](https://orgmode.org/) might be what you're looking for. It has very flexible scheduling mechanisms for TODOs. While many other apps only schedule fixed time intervals, in org-mode you can schedule e.g. "9 days after the last schedule time", "9 days after the last finish time" etc.